# Numpy matrix of coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, coordinates

I'm trying to get a matrix of coordinate-arrays. This is different from numpy.meshgrid. For example, for a 2x2 size I'd want the 2x2x2 output

```
[[[0,0],[0,1]],
 [[1,0],[1,1]]]
```

as a numpy array. This probably looks and reads cleaner a 2x2 matrix of tuples:

```
[[(0,0),(0,1)],
 [(1,0),(1,1)]]
```

(except I don't think you can have tuples in a numpy array, and it's not the point here)

This simple example can be done by switching the axes of numpy-meshgrid's output (specifically, moving the first axis to be last):

```
np.array(np.meshgrid([0,1],[0,1])).transpose([1,2,0])
```

This could be easily generalized to arbitrary dimensions, except that meshgrid doesn't behave as I would expect for more than 2 inputs. Specifically, the returned matrices have coordinate values that vary along axes in an odd order:

```
In [627]: np.meshgrid([0,1],[0,1],[0,1])
Out[627]:
[array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 0],
        [1, 1]]]),
 array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1]]]),
 array([[[0, 1],
        [0, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])]
```

Notice that the elements of this output vary along axes 1, 0, and 2, respectively. This will build an incorrect coordinate matrix; I would need the output to vary along axes 0, 1, and 2, in that order. So I could do

```
In [642]: np.array(np.meshgrid([0,1],[0,1],[0,1])).swapaxes(1,2)
Out[642]:
array([[[[0, 0],
         [0, 0]],

        [[1, 1],
         [1, 1]]],


       [[[0, 0],
         [1, 1]],

        [[0, 0],
         [1, 1]]],


       [[[0, 1],
         [0, 1]],

        [[0, 1],
         [0, 1]]]])
```

But this is starting to get really hacky and I don't know if I can count on this order in higher-dimension meshgrid outputs. numpy.mgrid gives the right order, but doesn't seem to allow arbitrary values, which I will need. So this boils down to two questions:

1) Is there a cleaner way, maybe some function in numpy I'm missing, that will generate a matrix of coordinate-vectors as described?
2) Is this odd ordering really what we expect from meshgrid? Is there a spec to this point that I can count on?

[EDIT] Following up on Jaime's solution, here's a more generalized function to build it a little more explicitly for anyone interested: [EDIT 2, fixed a bug, might be another, can't spend much more time on this right now, this really needs to be a more common function...]

```
def build_coords(*vecs):
    coords = numpy.empty(map(len,vecs)+[len(vecs)])
    for ii in xrange(len(vecs)):
        s = np.hstack((len(vecs[ii]), np.ones(len(vecs)-ii-1)))
        v = vecs[ii].reshape(s)
        coords[...,ii] = v
    return coords
```

Comment: what I like to do is keep two arrays: one for the x-coords and the other for the y-coords. Then you can just create the coordinate pairs by accessing elements both from both arrays with identical indices. Not sure if that'll work for you, but that's my take on these situations.

Comment: I like to do pauls method ... but for points i zip x and y together

Comment: I actually need the whole matrix in this case; the goal is to evaluate a multivariate function at a specified grid of coordinates. Perhaps the solution would be to rewrite the function to accept a tuple of (x, y, z, ...) values instead of a matrix of coordinate-vectors, but then I still have the issue of generating these in the correct orientation, which meshgrid seems not to do for some reason. I really feel like this is a bug in meshgrid, is it not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `np.meshgrid([0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], indexing="ij")`. The `meshgrid` docs are actually pretty explicit about how the default `indexing="xy"` produces a funny axis ordering as compared to the non-default `indexing="ij"`, so you can check that for more details. (They're not as clear on *why* it works this way, alas...)

Answer (score 21):

The numpy function [`indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) can also be used to this effect, its functionality being clear from its name as well.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.indices((2,3))
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]])
```

which can be thought of as a 2 by 3 matrix of y coordinates and a 2 by 3 matrix of x coordinates (`y,x = np.indices((2,3))`). It can be recast into the form proposed by Jaime by transposing the axes:

```
>>> np.indices((2,3)).transpose((1,2,0))
```

It is functionally equivalent to [the `meshgrid` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27258410/2476444), using `indexing='ij'`, but does not require you to provide the coordinate arrays, which can be a benefit when you have many dimensions.

```
>>> def f1(shape):
...     return np.array(np.meshgrid(*(np.arange(s) for s in shape), indexing='ij'))
...
>>> shape = (200, 31, 15, 4)
>>> np.all(f1(shape) == np.indices(shape))
True
```

Timing wise, these solutions are similar, when you take into account the time required for generating the 1-D arrays on which `meshgrid` operates, but `meshgrid` returns a list (of arrays), not an nd-array like `indices`. By adding an extra call to `np.array` as done in `f1` above, `indices` has a clear advantage over `meshgrid`:

```
In [14]: %timeit f1(shape)
100 loops, best of 3: 14 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit np.indices(shape)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.77 ms per loop
```

Without the extra call to `array`:

```
In [16]: def f2(shape):
    return np.meshgrid(*(np.arange(s) for s in shape), indexing='ij')
   .....: 

In [17]: %timeit f2(shape)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.78 ms per loop
```

Always be careful with interpreting timings though. This likely won't be the bottleneck in any problem you tackle.

In any case, `meshgrid` can do many more things than `indices` can, such as generating a more general [rectilinear grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grid) instead of a Cartesian grid, so use them when appropriate. In this case, I'd go with the naming-wise more descriptive `indices`.

Comment: Looks like someone was frustrated enough yesterday to downvote this (not too bad) answer and another answer of mine in the same timespan. Too bad he/she has such a mindset, taking frustrations out on decent answers, StackOverflow would be nicer without it. Anyway, to future readers: don't let the below zero score detract you from the answer: `np.indices` works and was made with exactly this goal in mind.

Answer (score 8):

Given the 1D coords:

```
rows = np.arange(2)
cols = np.arange(3)
```

I was hoping that this would do the trick:

```
np.dstack((rows[:, None, None], cols[:, None]))
```

But apparently `dstack` and the like require exactly matching dimensions, they will not broadcast them, which I think is a shame.

So this alternative is a little long, but explicit is better than implicit, and you can always wrap it all into a little function:

```
>>> coords = np.empty((len(rows), len(cols), 2), dtype=np.intp)
>>> coords[..., 0] = rows[:, None]
>>> coords[..., 1] = cols

>>> coords
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 2]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2]]])
```

Comment: This is great. I just still really wish my meshgrid one-liner would work! But for anyone interested, [edit, I guess code in comments is a no-go], [second edit, I don't think I want to click "answer your question" either] I've added it to the question description

Answer (score 2):

The original question was posted six years ago, but I have found myself repeatedly searching for good approaches to this problem and landed here many times. Looking through the Numpy documentation I recently put together an intuitive and dynamic approach for generating n-dimensional coordinates and wanted to post it here for those still hitting this answer.

We use [`numpy.ndindex()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html#numpy.ndindex) which:

> Given the shape of an array, an ndindex instance iterates over the N-dimensional index of the array. At each iteration a tuple of indices is returned, the last dimension is iterated over first.

The best way to understand is to look at an example:

```
In [100]: for index in np.ndindex(2,2,2):
              print(index)
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
```

That is exactly what we are looking for, so how do we get it into a numpy array format or as a list?

If we want the coordinates as a list we can use:

```
In [103]: coordList = [x for x in np.ndindex(2,2,2)]
In [104]: print(coordList)
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

And if we want the coordinates as a numpy array we can use:

```
In [105]: coordArray = np.stack([x for x in np.ndindex(2,2,2)])
In [106]: print(coordArray)
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 1]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 1 1]]
```

This approach easily scales with varying dimensions and sizes, and with `numpy.reshape()` we can get exactly the format OP is looking for:

```
In [117]: answer = np.stack([x for x in np.ndindex(2,2)]).reshape(2,2,2)
In [118]: print(answer)
[[[0 0]
  [0 1]]

 [[1 0]
  [1 1]]]
```

Which, again, easily extends to larger dimensions:

```
In [120]: example = np.stack([x for x in np.ndindex(3,3,3)]).reshape(3,3,3,3)
In [121]: print(example)
[[[[0 0 0]
   [0 0 1]
   [0 0 2]]

  [[0 1 0]
   [0 1 1]
   [0 1 2]]

  [[0 2 0]
   [0 2 1]
   [0 2 2]]]


 [[[1 0 0]
   [1 0 1]
   [1 0 2]]

  [[1 1 0]
   [1 1 1]
   [1 1 2]]

  [[1 2 0]
   [1 2 1]
   [1 2 2]]]


 [[[2 0 0]
   [2 0 1]
   [2 0 2]]

  [[2 1 0]
   [2 1 1]
   [2 1 2]]

  [[2 2 0]
   [2 2 1]
   [2 2 2]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way that I use is the following-

```
x,y = np.mgrid[-10:10:0.1, -10:10:0.1]
pos = np.empty(x.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = x; pos[:, :, 1] = y
pos = np.reshape(pos, (x.shape[0]*x.shape[1], 2))
```

The `pos` is the required coordinates array.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I found so far:

```py
height = 2
width = 4
t = np.mgrid[:height, :width]
t = np.stack((t[0], t[1]), axis=2)

>>> t
array([
 [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3]],
 [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
])
```

And if you are looking to do the same in tensorflow:

```py
rows = tf.range(0, img0.shape[1]) # generate row numbers
cols = tf.range(0, img0.shape[2]) # generate col numbers
cols, rows = tf.meshgrid(cols, rows) # expend them to a grid
z = tf.stack((cols, rows), axis=2) # stack them together
z = tf.stack([z]*img0.shape[0], axis=0) # stack up to number of batches
```