# Create 2D array from point x,y using numpy

Tags: numpy

With a position x,y as 30,40 as the top left corner of a 30 by 30 pixels (900 pixels total) grid I want to create an array with these x,y points using numpy. I've tried with a list and for loop but it seems slow I hope numpy will be faster.

Comment: I think this answer has a solution for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32208565/5207081

Answer (score 1):

## source: [Numpy matrix of coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436063/numpy-matrix-of-coordinates)

Something like this?

```
import numpy as np

rows = np.arange(30,60)
cols = np.arange(40,70)

coords = np.empty((len(rows), len(cols), 2), dtype=np.intp)

coords[..., 0] = rows[:, None]
coords[..., 1] = cols
```

Comment: Not really this, it should return an array like [[30,40],[31,40],[32,40],...,[90,110]]

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri That creates a bigger matrix than you originally asked for or am I missing smh?